# Display only folders from a zip archive

Tags: c#, zip, directory, names

How do I display only folders' names from a zip archive without unzip it using C#?

How do I treat the case when a folder is called abc.csv?

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service: please show what you have tried so far. (Also, why would a folder called `abc.csv` need special handling?)

Comment: As programmer I mus treat ALL possible situations.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is using the examples from the lib [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) slightly modified. This is from their examples section, so I have not tried to compile this fyi.

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
{
  if (header)
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Zipfile: {0}", zip.Name);
    if ((zip.Comment != null) && (zip.Comment != "")) 
      System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", zip.Comment);
    System.Console.WriteLine("\n{1,-22} {2,8}  {3,5}   {4,8}  {5,3} {0}",
                             "Filename", "Modified", "Size", "Ratio", "Packed", "pw?");
    System.Console.WriteLine(new System.String('-', 72));
    header = false;
  }
  System.Console.WriteLine("{1,-22} {2,8} {3,5:F0}%   {4,8}  {5,3} {0}",
                           e.FileName,
                           e.LastModified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                           e.UncompressedSize,
                           e.CompressionRatio,
                           e.CompressedSize,
                           (e.UsesEncryption) ? "Y" : "N");
  if(e.IsDirectory)
  {
   //Add to a list or whatever it is you wanna do
  }

 }
}
```